# Simplifying compound propositions

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I am struggling greatly with simplifying compound statements within propositional calculus. I have read textbooks and watched YouTube tutorials, but they always deal with the same (very simple) problems. Whilst these are somewhat helpful in explaining things like DeMorgan's theorem, and expanding brackets, etc. I am struggling when simplifying longer statements. For all I know the statement is as simple as possible already, and that's why my efforts fail...

I have to prove logical validity for the statement below, and I have achieved that using a 64 row truth table, but feel there must be another way (by simplifying the statement).

(A ⇒ F ∧ L) ∧ (F ⇒ M ∧ S) ∧ (M ⇒ R) ⇒ (A ⇒ L ∧ R)

I get this far and then am lost:

¬((¬A ∨ (F ∧ L)) ∧ (¬F ∨ (M ∧ S)) ∧ (¬M ∨ R)) ∨ (¬A ∨ (L ∨ R))

I feel it might be worth mentioning that I have previously gone much further than that step, but seem to always end up with something not equivalent to the original statement, so I'm definitely doing something wrong!

⇒ = IMPLIES
¬ = NOT
∧ = AND
∨ = OR

### THE SOLUTION

#### (Thank you Zar)

Take the first part of the statement (before the conclusion) and multiply out the brackets.

(A ⇒ F ∧ L) ∧ (F ⇒ M ∧ S) ∧ (M ⇒ R) **becomes**
(A ⇒ F ∧ A ⇒ L) ∧ (F ⇒ M ∧ F ⇒ S) ∧ (M ⇒ R)

We then also know that A ⇒ F, F ⇒ M, and M ⇒ R. So, A ⇒ R and we can get rid of F and M from the statement

A ⇒ L stays the same, as there is no way to simplify this.

This means that (So Far, A ⇒ R ∧ A ⇒ L).

A ⇒ F and F ⇒ S, so A ⇒ S

This leaves A ⇒ R and A ⇒ L and A ⇒ S (A ⇒ R ∧ A ⇒ L ∧ A ⇒ S).

Factorise the brackets to get:
A ⇒ (R ∧ L ∧ S)

Finally, add this back at the start of the statement to get our simplified compound statement:
(A ⇒ (R ∧ L ∧ S)) ⇒ (A ⇒ L ∧ R)
You can actually take out the S, as it's not necessary to prove validity, and swap the R ∧ L around to get L ∧ R, and all of a sudden both sides match perfectly and it's easy to see at a glance that this is a tautology.
(A ⇒ L ∧ R) ⇒ (A ⇒ L ∧ R)

Comment: Does $A \implies B \land C$ mean $(A \implies B) \land C$ or $A \implies (B \land C)$?

Comment: This compound statement has been translated from atomic statements used in a paragraph. So my example (A ⇒ F ∧ L)  stands for the sentence: If the operator activates the alarm, then the fail-safe mechanism is set into operation and the event is logged. With A = operator activates alarm, F = fail-safe mechanism is set into operation, and L = event is logged.
TL;DR: A⟹(B∧C)

Comment: Your statement is a tautology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $A\Rightarrow F\wedge L$ you have $A \Rightarrow F$ and $A \Rightarrow L$.

From $F\Rightarrow M\wedge S$ you have $F\Rightarrow M$.

From $F\Rightarrow M$ and $M\Rightarrow R$ you have $F\Rightarrow R$.

From $A\Rightarrow F$ and  $F\Rightarrow R$ you have $A\Rightarrow R$.

And now, from $A\Rightarrow R$ and $A \Rightarrow L$, you have
$A\Rightarrow L\wedge R$.

Comment: (That's assuming $A\Rightarrow B\wedge C$ means $A\Rightarrow(B\wedge C$)

Comment: This looks like a great method to construct a formal proof, but still leaves me somewhat baffled. Are you saying that A⇒L∧R is the simplification of the whole statement? :S

Comment: No, the simplification should be $A\Rightarrow(L\wedge R\wedge S\wedge M)$

Comment: No, the simplification is $\top$, because it is a tautology.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the semplification of the term (A ⇒ F ∧ L) ∧ (F ⇒ M ∧ S) ∧ (M ⇒ R)

Comment: Ah, I get it now! I was struggling with multiplying out the brackets. That's perfect. So that leaves me with (A⇒(L∧R∧S∧M)) ⇒ (A ⇒ L ∧ R).
Is there any way to simplify this further?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to simplify: the entire expression is a tautology, so that's the complete simplification. And the fact that $A\Rightarrow(L\wedge R)$ is a direct consequence of the premises.

Comment: I have exams coming up which ask me to take atomic sentences from a paragraph and create statements which prove (or disprove) the overall validity of a paragraph using a truth table. Truth tables are a pain to write out by hand when using 5 or more atomic sentences, so I'm trying to simplify the compound statement to make smaller truth tables. This was suggested by my professor, but he said it wasn't completely necessary,  so didn't spend too much time on it. I've taken out the M (as A implies F implies M implies R) and now have: (A ⇒ (L ∧ S ∧ R)) ⇒ (A ⇒ L ∧ R).

Comment: Of course, I could use a computer for the truth tables, but 1) that doesn't prove I really understand all of this, and 2) I don't get a computer during the exams. ;)

Comment: Ok, I understand. You can take out $S$ too, then (and the tautology emerges).

Answer (score 0):

Using [SymPy Live](http://live.sympy.org),

```
>>> A, F, L, M, R, S = symbols('A F L M R S')
>>> Phi = ((A >> (F & L)) & (F >> (M & S)) & (M >> R)) >> (A >> (L & R))
>>> simplify(Phi)
True
```

What is the CNF?

```
>>> to_cnf(Phi)
And(Or(A, F, L, M, Not(A)), Or(A, F, L, Not(A), Not(R)), Or(A, F, M, R, Not(A)), Or(A, F, R, Not(A), Not(R)), Or(A, L, M, Not(A), Not(M), Not(S)), Or(A, L, Not(A), Not(M), Not(R), Not(S)), Or(A, M, R, Not(A), Not(M), Not(S)), Or(A, R, Not(A), Not(M), Not(R), Not(S)), Or(F, L, M, Not(A), Not(F), Not(L)), Or(F, L, Not(A), Not(F), Not(L), Not(R)), Or(F, M, R, Not(A), Not(F), Not(L)), Or(F, R, Not(A), Not(F), Not(L), Not(R)), Or(L, M, Not(A), Not(F), Not(L), Not(M), Not(S)), Or(L, Not(A), Not(F), Not(L), Not(M), Not(R), Not(S)), Or(M, R, Not(A), Not(F), Not(L), Not(M), Not(S)), Or(R, Not(A), Not(F), Not(L), Not(M), Not(R), Not(S)))
```

What is the DNF?

```
>>> to_dnf(Phi)
Or(And(A, Not(F)), And(A, Not(L)), And(F, Not(M)), And(F, Not(S)), And(L, R), And(M, Not(R)), Not(A))
```